# Почему скрипт не у всех картинок выводит title?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если на странице несколько изображений, которые соответствуют всем условиям в скрипте, то `title` выводится у всех картинок. Если же на странице много картинок, например, около двадцати или даже более, и все картинки также соответствую всем условиям в скрипте, то `title` выводится лишь у нескольких первых картинок, а у остальных не выводится. Как-то это не поддается никакой логике. Почему так, и как это можно устранить?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  newsImg = $(".news img");
  newsImg.after(function() {
    imgTitle = $(this).attr("title");
    if (imgTitle && imgTitle != '' && $(this).width() > 500 && $(this).css('float') == 'none') return "<div class='img_title'>" + imgTitle + "</div>";
  });
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65240/discussion-on-question-by-ladyx--------title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с ожиданием события `load` для `window` (ожидание загрузки всех картинок перед выполнением скрипта):

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  var $newsImg = $(".news img");
  $newsImg.after(function() {
    var imgTitle = this.title;
    if (imgTitle && imgTitle != '' && $(this).width() > 500 && $(this).css('float') == 'none')
      return "<div class='img_title'>" + imgTitle + "</div>";
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="news">
  <img title="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x50" />
  <img title="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x60" />
  <img title="img3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x70" />
  <img title="img4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x80" />
  <img title="img5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x90" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Вариант с ожиданием события `load` для каждой картинки отдельно (без установки `src` в JS, на базе [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3537471/3432401)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $newsImg = $(".news img");
  $newsImg.one("load", function() {
    $(this).after(function() {
      var imgTitle = this.title;
      if (imgTitle && imgTitle != '' && $(this).width() > 500 && $(this).css('float') == 'none')
        return "<div class='img_title'>" + imgTitle + "</div>";
    });
  }).each(function() {
    if (this.complete)
      $(this).trigger("load");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="news">
  <img title="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x51" />
  <img title="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x61" />
  <img title="img3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x71" />
  <img title="img4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x81" />
  <img title="img5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x91" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @LADYX попробуйте `$newsImg.one(...` вместо `$newsImg.on(...`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    newsImg = $(".fullstory img");
    newsImg.after(function() {
        imgTitle = $(this).attr("title");
        if (imgTitle && imgTitle != '' && $(this).width() > 500 && $(this).css('float') == 'none') return "<span class='img_title'>" + imgTitle + "</span>";
    });
});
```